# How to insert external RTF tables to word document using R

Tags: r, rtf

I have a bunch of existing RTF tables and would like to add them to .docx file  when using R package "ReporteRs". But it dose not support external RTF table yet. So I am trying to insert file path to the .docx file and toggle the link to get the table. To do that, I need to add a pair of braces "{}" around the file path. But simply adding symbol "{}" around the file path will not do the work since the braces will be translated to some RTF codes in word and the background RTF code for "{}" is actually quite complicated. Now, my questions are:

(1) How to add resolvable braces "{}" around the rtf file path so that I can toggle the link. I tried to use the rtf code I found to replace the braces, but it can not be complied to braces by Microsoft WORD. The rtf code I found is like this:

{\field{*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af31503 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid8593807 \hich\af31502\dbch\af31501\loch\f31502  \hich\af31502\dbch\af31501\loch\f31502 
INCLUDETEXT  "\\\\ my file pth\d0blchar.rtf" \c MSRTF\hich\af31502\dbch\af31501\loch\f31502  }}

I hope this can be resolved by WORD to something like:
{INCLUDETEXT  "\\ my file pth\d0blchar.rtf" \c MSRTF }

But it seems to me that WORD can not do the compiling.

(2) If (1) is not workable, is there any other R package which can include RTF tables to a WORD file when creating a WORD file by R?

## My sample code is attached:

```
library(ReporteRs)
path<-'\\\\\\\\mypath\\data\\table1.rtf' #path for the related TLFS
report<-docx()                           #initialize the docx object

text1<-"{\\field{\\*\\fldinst {\\rtlch\\fcs1 \\af31503 \\ltrch\\fcs0 \\insrsid8593807 \\hich\\af31502\\dbch\\af31501\\loch\\f31502  \\hich\\af31502\\dbch\\af31501\\loch\\f31502  "
text2<-"\\hich\\af31502\\dbch\\af31501\\loch\\f31502  }}"

fileAdd<-paste0(text1,"INCLUDETEXT \"", path, "\" \\c MSRTF", text2)
report<-addParagraph(report,fileAdd) #add rtf tables
writeDoc(report, file="Report.docx") #output the docx file
```

============================================

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried the rtf package instead? If you have Windows, R2wd seems to be in a more stable version.

Comment: Thanks @noumenal. No I did not try rtf or R2wd package. I check their documents. The functions in the two packages look similar to those in package "ReporteRs".They do not have functions to add external rtf table either.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to copy a table from a RTF document to a Word document with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)

wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
path_To_RTF_File <- "D:\\Doc_Table_RTF.rtf"
path_To_Word_File <- "D:\\empty_Word.docx"

doc_RTF <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_RTF_File), ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

doc <- wordApp[["ActiveDocument"]]
tbl <- doc$Tables(1)

doc_Word_File <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_To_Word_File), ConfirmConversions = FALSE)

rngTableTarget <- doc_Word_File$content()
rngTableTarget$Collapse(0)
rngTableTarget[["FormattedText"]] <- tbl$Range()$FormattedText()
```